# Adding python into path

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, path

I am trying to add a new version of python-(python3.8.2) instead of python(3.7)- into the path,but when i try to run python in cmd  it ran 3.7 so I uninstalled it then this happened , what can I do to run the new version of python in cmd m[image]

Comment: whats in your environment variables?

Answer (score 0):

2 ways:

1. If you want to keep both versions then just use py-launcher i.e., type "py -3.7" or "py -.38" in  cmd to run respective python versions.
2. Remove the path of the python version you don't want.

Currently most probably your python 3.7 version's .exe file is not removed and the path still exists in the Environment Variables just remove the path from there.

Answer (score 0):

For Win 10:

```
1) Open System Properties - right click Computer in the start menu

2) Click Advanced system settings in the sidebar

3) Click Environment Variables

4) Select PATH in the System variables section and click Edit

5) Find and replace the path of python(3.7) from there with (python3.8.2)
```

Done

Comment: I tried to reinstall (python3.7.7) it worked again , so I tried to do what you told mebut still it"s not working.

Comment: Open Command Prompt from the start menu and type "where Python". It will display paths of all installed Python versions. Check that path of new version python with the one in Environment Variables. It may give you some clue.

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling python 3.8 again and see if it works, i think it will edit and change to the correct path